# I have a batch file that opens a specific website. Is there additional code I can add to open said website at a zoom level of 90%?

Tags: batch-file, web, automation

I have a batch file that opens a specific website. Is there additional code I can add to open said website at a zoom level of 90%?

Here is the current code in my .bat file:

```bash
@echo off
start "" https://tasks.office.com/TOYOTA1.onmicrosoft.com/Home/PlanViews/LehawuW12UCpPlE1sLCGpGQAGu17?Type=PlanLink&Channel=Link&CreatedTime=638318617565650000 
exit
```

Comment: short (and dissatisfying) answer: no. `Cmd` is not built to interact with graphical applications. It can only start them, but then there is no way to interact with them. Except your browser has a command line option to set the zoom level (which is very  unlikely). (Btw: I removed your `zoom-sdk` tag, because your question has nothing to do with that communication software.)

Comment: you can try with [sendkeys](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat) and ctrl+

Comment: The command `exit` at end of the batch file should be removed from the batch file. It is always unnecessary at end of a batch file and is just counterproductive on being used at the end of a batch file.

Comment: @npocmaka I had the same idea. But how to keep track of the current zoom factor?

Answer (score 0):

After zooming in and out unfortunate stackoverflow site a little, here a - more or less - working solution:

```batch
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=. " %%I IN ('ver') DO SET /A VERSION=%%I > NUL
IF NOT DEFINED VERSION EXIT /B 1

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

SET "APPPATH="

IF %VERSION% GTR 8 (
   FOR /F "tokens=3" %%R IN ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice" /V "ProgId"') DO SET "HTTPREF=%%R"
   IF NOT DEFINED HTTPREF EXIT /B 1
   FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%R IN ('reg query "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\!HTTPREF!\shell\open\command" /VE') DO SET "HTTPAPP=%%S"
   IF NOT DEFINED HTTPAPP EXIT /B 1
   CALL :PathParams HTTPAPP
) ELSE (
   FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%R IN ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\htmlfile\Shell\open\command" /VE') DO SET "HTTPAPP=%%S"
   IF NOT DEFINED HTTPAPP EXIT /B 1
   CALL :PathParams HTTPAPP
)

IF "%APPPATH%" == "" (
   ECHO No default browser found.
   GOTO :EndOfBatch
)

REM CTR + + zomm in
REM CTR + - zomm out
REM CTR + 0 reset zoom <- works in edge and chrome 8-)

"%APPPATH%" "https://stackoverflow.com"

REM If the above is not working remove it and add
REM START "" "URL"

SET "TEMPFILE=%temp%\script-hotkey-ctrl-0-ctrl-minus.vbs"
IF NOT EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" (
    >"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO Wscript.Sleep 1000
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "^0"
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "^-"
)

IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" (
   CSCRIPT //nologo "%TEMPFILE%"
)


GOTO :EndOfBatch


:PathParams
SET RES=!%~1!
SET RES=%RES:"=%
SET APPPARAMS=%RES:*.exe=%
IF "%APPPARAMS%" == "" (
   SET "APPPATH=%RES%"
) ELSE (
   SET "APPPATH=!RES:%APPPARAMS%=!"
)
EXIT /B


:EndOfBatch
ECHO.
ECHO Exiting batch now...
ECHO.
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 200 >NUL
ENDLOCAL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
GOTO :Exit


:Exit
```

Unfortunately this is not pure batch (hotkeys).

The hotkey Ctrl + 0 (cero) first resets the browser to 100% (at least in chrome and edge).

Then the hotkey Ctrl + - zooms out (or in whatever).

It reads the registry to determine the default browser to handle possible other browser hotkeys (in future ).

I tested it in Windows 10; if the registry part won't work, you can remove it and paste the url as it was in the `start` command.

Going through every browser and looking for separate solutions seems very time-consuming to me.

e.g. Chrome has a lot of command line arguments:
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Another thing that could be useful is to wait for the window and make sure it has focus. If desired, I can add that.

Regarding Mofi's comment:
"The command exit at end of the batch file should be removed from the batch file. It is always unnecessary at end of a batch file and is just counterproductive on being used at the end of a batch file."

It closes the Command Prompt Window instead of `EXIT /B` which is unnecessary at end of batch - so no **it's not** counterproductive and no **it's not** "always unnecessary".

Edit: Minimalistic version

```batch
@ECHO OFF
SET "TEMPFILE=%temp%\script-hotkey-ctrl-0-ctrl-minus.vbs"
SET "InitWait=2000"
SET "KeyWait=200"
REM ' <- WScript comment; Change the number to write a new file.
SET "VERSION='V1"
IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" ( SET /P UPDATE=<"%TEMPFILE%" ) ELSE ( SET "UPDATE= " )
REM Compare first line to not always write a file if not necessary.
IF NOT "%UPDATE%" == "%VERSION%" (
    >"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO %VERSION%
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
   REM Initial sleep in milliseconds for browser opens page; if you scroll horizontal by arrow keys the page must be loaded already.
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO Wscript.Sleep %InitWait%
   REM ^ caret = CONTROL ergo CTRL + 0  / KeyWait to sleep before every keystroke a little, so app can update.
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "^0"
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO Wscript.Sleep %KeyWait%
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "^-"
   REM Send arrow right multiple times... you can repeat a keystroke by set a number (RIGHT 20 times)
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO Wscript.Sleep %KeyWait%
   >>"%TEMPFILE%" ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT 20}"
)
IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" (
   START "" "https://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html"
   CSCRIPT //nologo "%TEMPFILE%"
)
```

Comment: Regarding your comment regarding Mofi's comment, there's no reason to ever close the command prompt window at the end of execution. None. In fact, the vast majority of the time, you want the window to _stay_ open so that you can either read output from the script or rerun the script. It's also worth noting that if you double-click the script to run it for some reason, the window will close once the script ends no matter what.

Comment: @SomethingDark You contradict yourself, sir. It's not a matter of whether you see any sense in it, but whether it makes a difference.

Comment: `exit` at the end of the script is unnecessary if you're running it by double-clicking it because the window is going to close anyway, and if you want to want the window to close when you run it from the command line, then you are wrong for doing so.

Comment: @SomethingDark Just because you open your batch with a double click, should exit be redundant? Did the OP write that he opens his batch by double-clicking? Think of a sub using start /B, for example,  where exit makes sense even if you dc your bat to open it... Or if you CMD /K for some reason.

Comment: The correct way to run a script from inside of another script is to use `call`, not `start`. You keep coming up with these ridiculous hypotheticals that will never happen if the person writing the code is even remotely competent. And imo you should never write a script that forces the window to close.

Comment: @SomethingDark How do you use a `call` without having to wait for it to finish...? An example would be great, then I could learn something new.

Comment: @7three it worked thanks! If I am using Edge as my default browser, is there any part of the code I can remove?

Comment: @7three, also if my browser always opens at 100%, and I can get to 90% by clicking "ctrl -" one time, is there a simple way to have the code send a "ctrl -" click for me? I know npocmaka recommended that above, but when I go to the link posted, not sure if I need all that code to send a "ctrl -". Thanks!

Comment: @g.texas What do you mean by "clicking"? The script sends the keystroke CONTROL SUBSTRACT? I thought you want to open a specific page like this and not several or all of them? Concerning remove some code: Yes I can update my answer, as soon as I understand what you mean.

Comment: @7three, this is perfect, love the minimalistic version. Also very cool stars website.

Sorry, not click but send keystrokes "ctrl -", which I believe you already provided so I should be all set. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, is it possible to scroll the site to the right in the code? It could either scroll all the way to the right, or even better would be a specified amount that I could play with to get exact. This is a to do list for several people, and my name is further to the right, so I always have to scroll when opening. The 90% shows my name when scrolling fully right, but if I could calibrate the amount then I could go back to 100% zoom.

Comment: @g.texas You could achieve this by right arrow key. I'll add it to your minimalistic version. Also delete the old script is needed.

Comment: @g.texas Now that I understand what the goal of the exercise is: It could be that your page has an "anchor" and/or a "name" attribute. In that case, you could simply enter “#yourName” at the end of the URL. Maybe you would come to the name straight away.